# WaitNamedPipe() returns 0 With More Than 2 Clients in Windows XP

Tags: c++, windows

I am creating a client connection using Windows XP as a server, and clients (8 clients) are Windows NT.

However, only 2 clients can connect to the server.

I also tried it using Windows Server 2003 as a server, and Windows XP for the clients. With this configuration, all 8 clients can connect to the server.

Is there a limitation on the connection when using Windows XP as a server?

My error code from `GetLastError()` is 71 (`ERROR_REQ_NOT_ACCEP`, "No more connections can be made to this remote computer at this time because there are already as many connections as the computer can accept.")

Below is my code:

```cpp
BOOL CClientPipeInstance::Write(LPCTSTR szData){
    ASSERT(szData);
    ASSERT(AfxIsValidString(szData));

    DWORD          dwDataLen,
                   dwError;
    CSleeper       ss;
    CSecurityToken sa;

    if (m_csPipename.IsEmpty())
        return FALSE;
    
    try
    {
        if (m_hPipe == HANDLE(NULL))
        {
            if (WaitNamedPipe(m_csPipename, PIPE_WAIT_TIME))
            {
                while (TRUE)
                {
                    if ((m_hPipe = CreateFile(m_csPipename, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, &sa, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL)) != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
                    {
                        output("Create Pipe File OK");
                        m_isPipeOn = true;
                        return WriteFile(m_hPipe, szData, _tcslen(szData), &dwDataLen, NULL);
                    }
                    else if (GetLastError() == ERROR_PIPE_BUSY)
                    {
                        ss.Sleep(50);
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        warning("Create Pipe File is NOT OK");
                        return FALSE;
                    }
                }
            }
            warning("PIPE Wait Time Out with ErrorNum %d", GetLastError() );
            return FALSE;
        }
        else if (WriteFile(m_hPipe, szData, _tcslen(szData), &dwDataLen, NULL) == 0)
        {
            dwError = GetLastError();
            warning("Error Broken Pipe with ErrorNum %d", dwError);
            if (dwError == ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE)
            {
                //  Our pipe went away
                CloseHandle(m_hPipe);
                m_hPipe = HANDLE(NULL);
                m_isPipeOn = false;
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        warning("Caught unknown exception in CClientPipeInstance::Send");
        TRACE("Caught unknown exception in CClientPipeInstance::Send\n");
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

`m_csPipename` is already created with the servername format (`\\\servername\pipe\pipename`).

My question are as follows:

1. `WaitNamedPipe()` returns 0 for clients 3 to 8, even if the pipename is already created.
2. Is there a limitation on Windows XP that only allows 2 clients?
3. If there is a limitation, how to configure it to allow more than 2 clients?

Comment: XP isn't a server operating system so had various arbitrary limits to stop you using it as a server

Comment: @AlanBirtles even so, it did not have such a restrictive limit that only 2 clients could connect at a time. I've written servers on XP and could connect more clients than that.

Comment: thanks for your comments.. is it also related to the settings of the windows firewall? Or if the windows XP is connected into a domain server and might restrict the rights/privilege?

Comment: Named pipes use [smb](https://csandker.io/2021/01/10/Offensive-Windows-IPC-1-NamedPipes.html) maybe other smb connections are using the other 8 connections out of the allowed 10. Upgrading to a less ancient os might help, for example I believe Windows 7 raises the smb limit to a massive 20

Comment: I think that pipe behavior is just an effect. *XP* is not a **server *OS***, and it has some limitations related to incoming connections. For example (hope I remember correctly) the number of users simultaneously connected (via *RDP*) is limited. It also depends on what flavor do you have (*Home*, *Pro*, ...). Try using a *Win* server version as a server, and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Actually, when I used a Windows Server 2003 with clients using Windows XP, I did not encounter any issue during client connection. However, the actual implementation would be Windows XP will act as a server and Windows NT for the clients. And hoping for any feedback to fix the issue stated above.

Comment: I think that's your answer, use a server os (preferably one that is still actually supported by Microsoft)